# How to keep a thread's object instantiated long enough for an event outside the thread?

Tags: multithreading, delphi, events, delphi-xe2

I'm working on a multi-threaded system which involves the thread notifying its parent of destruction of an object. The problem is, I need to allow that object to remain created long enough for this event to read this object, because I'm passing the object as one of the event's parameters. Currently, when this event is triggered, the object which is passed to the event is already destroyed from within the thread.

I don't want the thread to necessarily *wait* for this event to be completed, but rather know when this event has been triggered and *then* destroy the object. I want the code in the thread to continue no matter what, even if the object is still instantiated.

There's a list of these objects, and they're created from within a thread. The thread its self has events for when certain things happen to the objects in this list (specifically in this case the destruction of the object). I'm actually feeding these events into an event queue (a TList which contains record pointers to what event and what object). So somewhere inside the thread, I add a record to this event list.

The thread's execution then comes along and loops through the events in this list and triggers them accordingly (example below). So when the event was added to the list, it saved the object pointer as part of this event's record pointer. There could then be a long delay until the event is actually triggered. At that point, the object needs to still be instantiated so it can be read from outside the thread. Only then shall the object actually be destroyed.

The mechanism used for this event queue doesn't have any room for feedback to the thread. It's already a developed system and any addition for this event queue to *tell the thread* that the event has been triggered is out of the question, as it would require an entire re-write. Otherwise, I would simply tell the thread to destroy this object once my event has been called.

Here's some snippets, the system is actually very large so it's difficult to show all the functionality. The one thread's event sets off a chain of events through 4 more parent objects, passing this object through each. The goal is to prevent any code outside of the thread to handle this actual destruction. The thread should take full responsibility for waiting for this event before destroying...

```
type
  TJDNetSvrNode = class;
  TJDNetSvrThread = class;

  TNodeEvent = (neUnload); //And many more

  PNodeEventRec = ^TNodeEventRec;
  TNodeEventRec = record
    Event: TNodeEvent;
    Node: TJDNetSvrNode;
  end;

  TJDNetSvrNodeEvent = procedure(Sender: TObject; Node: TJDNetSvrNode) of object;

  TJDNetSvrNode = class(TObject)
    //Large object with no relevant members
  end;

  TJDNetSvrThread = class(TThread)
  private
    FNodeEvents: TList;
    FNodeEvent: PNodeEventRec;
    FOnNodeUnload: TJDNetSvrNodeEvent;
    procedure SYNC_OnUnload;
  public
    property OnNodeUnload: TJDNetSvrNodeEvent read FOnNodeUnload write FOnNodeUnload;
  end; //Much more in this class

//Starting point of event - adds to event queue list
procedure TJDNetSvrThread.NodeUnloaded(Sender: TObject; Node: TJDNetSvrNode);
var
  E: PNodeEventRec;
begin
  E:= New(PNodeEventRec);
  E.Event:= neUnload;
  E.Node:= Node;
  FNodeEvents.Add(E);
end;

//Called within thread to execute any events which are queued
procedure TJDNetSvrThread.ProcessNodeEvents;
begin
  while FNodeEvents.Count > 0 do begin
    FNodeEvent:= PNodeEventRec(FNodeEvents[0]);
    FNodeEvents.Delete(0);
    case FNodeEvent.Event of
      neUnload: begin
        Synchronize(SYNC_OnUnload);
      end;
      //And many more
    end;
    Dispose(FNodeEvent);
  end;
end;

procedure TJDNetSvrThread.SYNC_OnUnload;
begin
  if assigned(FOnNodeUnload) then
    FOnNodeUnload(Self, FNodeEvent.Node); //Parent also has to use "Node" for its event
  //NOW "Node" can be destroyed
end;
```

Comment: I don't understand.  The 'SYNC_OnUnload' action routine is called using Synchronize() and so the event handler is also synchronized.  Why can you not just free the Node after the event handler has been called?  If the 'FOnNodeUnload' handler stores or queues off the Node to another thread, then the resposibility for freeing the Node should be stored or queued off with it.

Comment: If the event handler needs to be given the choice of 'keeping' the object or not, I usually pass the object into the event as a var parameter and free it afterwards if it's still assigned.  The event-handler can then choose to keep responsibility for the object by storing/queueing it and setting the passed reference to nil.

Comment: @MartinJames Because those Nodes are created/managed/destroyed from within a another object within the thread (which calls the event handler `TJDNetSvrThread.NodeUnloaded`). Sorry, I didn't point that out before. Technically even the thread (`TJDNetSvrThread`) shouldn't have anything to do with telling it to destroy either, but rather this sub-object (`TJDNetSvrNodes`) which contains this list of Node Objects. The only way I can see so far is to make `SYNC_OnUnload` free it right after the event call (as you mention), which I really don't want to destroy it from here.

Comment: ... Which does work fine, no doubt, just it's really sloppy to create an object from within one class and destroy it from a completely unaware object which is declared in fact in an entirely different unit.

Comment: 'really sloppy to create an object from within one class and destroy it from a completely unaware object which is declared in fact in an entirely different unit.' - unfortunately, it's almost an imperative when communicating between threads. The only alternative I know of is to recycle objects via a pool.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sounds like what you basically want is for an object to be able to be referenced from multiple different places in the system, and not get destroyed until after all the places referencing it are done with it, no matter what order that happens in.

Delphi has a mechanism to do exactly that: reference counting.  It's built in to the `Interface` model.  Try turning your object into a `TInterfacedObject` descendant, create and implement an `Interface` that exposes the functionality you need, and pass that around instead of the object reference.

Comment: If I PostMessage a refCounted interface and it subsequently drops out of scope or its variable is loaded with another interfacedObject in the posting procedure, can the implementation instance be destroyed before it can be processed in the target thread?

Comment: Yes. To avoid that, call the interface's `_AddRef()` method to increment the reference count just before calling `PostMessage()` and then have the message handler call the interface's `_Release()` method to decrement the reference count (don't forget to call `_Release()` if `PostMessage()` fails).

Comment: +1 I understand the idea of switching to an Interface, very reasonable approach, never used one though... just the couple comments above went WAY over my head...

Comment: Another way is to create copies of objects so as to avoid having to pass around ownership

Comment: Another way is to postpone object destruction/repooling until there is no chance that a normally operating app still might have or need a reference to it. Needs a timeout/delta-queue thread, but can be useful for some apps.

Comment: @RemyLebeau - I guess that the explicit _addref() call could be encapsulated in a 'PostInterfaceToMainThread' function/method.

Comment: @MartinJames That's actually the approach I'm about to do, like a ticking time bomb... Just after calling this synchronized procedure, I will light the fuse of this object, and it will blow (free) 1 minute later. I can see a chance that things might get fuzzy to the point where 30 seconds won't be enough (it's a very heavy-weight system) but 1 minute, indeed, no chance.